# Entering data onto php form, not populating MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Have a PHP form for a registration system:

```
         <div class="col-md-6 login-right">
    <h2> Register Here </h2>
    <form action="registration.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label> 
        <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label> 
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Register</button>
</form>
</div>
```

And a registration.php created:

```
    <?php   

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', 'test');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'userregistration');

$name = $_POST['user']; 
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$s = " select * from usertable where name = '$name'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
    echo " Username Already Taken";
}else{
    $reg = " insert into usertable(name , password) values ('$name' , $pass')";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    echo" Registration Successful";

}
?>
```

Also have a MySQL database created with Database: userregistration »Table: usertable. And the MySQL not sure, quite new to this isn't being populated with the inputted data from the php. When the data is inputted into the php form it requests the registration.php page which works successfully but doesn't populate the table with the data inputted.

Comment: __never__ store plain passwords in your database! use password_hash and password_verify!

Comment: generally: there's no need in rolling out your own authentication system. Use one of the many secure, maintained ones (from any popular framework)

Comment: please show your database definitions! The code shown should work (as far as I can tell after a quick look) - depending on what the db looks like

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the tip about password hash and verify. As far authentication systems popular framework any examples/tips on these. [DB Strucure](https://i.imgur.com/ZWNtoC1.png)  [DB Strucure](https://i.imgur.com/27NE5Wv.png) Are these what you're referring to as database definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be actively checking that the connection is successful first, and then also checking that the query was successfully executed too in order to debug this further.

```
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 


   if (mysqli_query($conn, $reg)) {
       echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
       echo "Error: " . $reg . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

You should then also close the connection